# Eigen Efficient Passing of Matrices

Tags: c++, performance, matrix, eigen, eigen3

I'm using Eigen in my application, and through profiling I have found code
similar to the following to be the bottleneck. The issue being memory
copying as the data is passed up to the usage (see below).

As is visible in the code, the "data" used for the matmat function can have
one of two origins, one is privately stored in the SMM class, while the other
is to be dynamically generated on the fly. This split is neccasary for my
application, but it is making it difficult to optimize. Were the source only
from the internal vector of data it seems to me that const Eigen::Refs would
be a simple solution. Perhaps it is due to the way my code is written, but
copy elision does not seem to be doing as much as I would hope it to. I
considered using shared_ptr to prevent copying the matrices around (which
can be quite large), but I'm not sure if that is the right direction to go.

It should be noted that the result of matmat never needs to be stored, it is
only ever used as a temporary variable in an Eigen expression

How can one efficiently pass matrices around in this case?

The following code is a simplification of the setup I am using.

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/StdVector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Eigen;
typedef MatrixXd MMatrix;

enum class Storage {Normal, On_The_Fly };

MMatrix matrixGen(int additional_data) {
  return additional_data *  MMatrix::Random(5, 5);
}

class SMM {
  private:
    std::vector<MMatrix, Eigen::aligned_allocator<MMatrix> > data_;

   //Provides controlled access to the data
    MMatrix get_data(int i, Storage mem, int additional_data = 0) {
      if (mem != Storage::On_The_Fly) {
        return data_[i];
      }
      else {
        return matrixGen(additional_data);
      }
    }
  public:
   // Only a placeholder constructor, in my actual program the building
   // is significantly more complex, and doesn't build the data immediately
   SMM(Storage mem) {
     if (mem == Storage::Normal) {
       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         data_.emplace_back(matrixGen(5));
       }
     }
    }


    //Similar to a matrix * matrix product
    MMatrix matmat(const MMatrix& A, int index, Storage mem, int additional_data = 0) {
      if (mem == Storage::On_The_Fly) {
        return this->get_data(index, mem, additional_data) * A;
      }
      else {
        return this->get_data(index, mem) * A;
      }
    }
};

int main() {
  Storage mem1 = Storage::Normal;
  Storage mem2 = Storage::On_The_Fly;
  SMM smm1 = SMM(mem1);
  SMM smm2 = SMM(mem2);
  MMatrix A = MMatrix::Random(5, 5);

  MMatrix B = MMatrix::Random(5, 5);
  MMatrix C = MMatrix::Random(5, 5);

  B += smm1.matmat(A, 2, mem1);
  C += smm2.matmat(A, 2, mem2, 5);
  std::cout << B << std::endl << std::endl;
  std::cout << C << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use a cache member variable:

```
class SMM {
  ...
  MMatrix cache_;
  const MMatrix& get_data(int i, Storage mem, int additional_data = 0) {
    if (mem != Storage::On_The_Fly) { return data_[i]; }
    else {
      matrixGenInPlace(additional_data,cache_);
      return cache_;
    }
  }
  ...
};
```

Comment: This works, although I've made the modification (outside the scope of the question) of using a vector for the cache (following Eigen allocation recommendations) as I am using OpenMP for multithreading, where each thread is doing a separate matmat. Thanks!

Comment: btw, no need to use an aligned_allocator for dynamically allocated Eigen's matrices. It is only required for fixed size ones like Matrix4d, Vector4f, etc.